# only first img tag keeps on changing from *ngFor li tag

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to create pop up description when mouse over

This is HTML code

```
  <div class = "col-12 container" id = {{i}}>
    <ul class= "list-unstyled row">
      <li *ngFor = "let z of data(m[m.length-1]) | slice: 0 : 10; index as j" class = "list-item col-6">
        <img id = "champ" src = {{z[0]}}/>
        <div id = "spells">
          <img (mouseover)="pop(z[1].description, $event)" (mouseout) = "desc = out()" src = {{z[1].spellurl}}/>
          <img (mouseover)="pop(z[2].description, $event)" (mouseout) = "desc = out()" src = {{z[2].spellurl}}/>
        </div>
        <div id = "desc"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

These are functions for mouseover and mouseout

```
    pop(desc: string, event){
    let ds = document.getElementById("desc");
    let pos = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    let newpos = "translate(" + pos.right + "px, " + pos.bottom+ "px)";
    ds.style.display = "block";
    ds.innerHTML = desc;
    ds.style.transform = newpos;
}
    out(){
    let ds = document.getElementById("desc");
    ds.style.display = "none";
}
```

This is a basic UI like this picture[image]

What I am trying to do is that when a mouse is over one of those small images, get a position of it and display the description DIV at the bottom of right side of the image.

A problem is that even though I tried to mouse over all the images all description div was displayed at the same position where I draw an arrow. So I did "inspect element" from browser to check HTML code and I found that ONLY first
`<div id = "desc">` from the first ngFor li tag was changing when mouse over.

I don't know why it is happening and event.target.getBoundingClientRect() is supposed to provide me current position of one element but it doesn't seem like it.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**. Use a class instead for `champ`, `spells` and `desc`

Comment: As @Andreas mentioned IDs definitely have to be unique. But, you might also want to include styles in the question to surely say if its the first id that is getting always picked (IMO).